# why is apt docs is missing? how to get it back?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, documentation

I'm reading the man page of apt and at the "see also" section it says:

`SEE ALSO
       apt-get(8), apt-cache(8), sources.list(5), apt.conf(5), apt-
       config(8), The APT User's guide in /usr/share/doc/apt-doc/,
       apt_preferences(5), the APT Howto.`

so I try `cd /usr/share/doc/apt-doc/`
and it returns: `bash: cd: /usr/share/doc/apt-doc/: No such file or directory`

What's up with that? Is this normal? Does this happen often with Linux often? When I was learning unix everything was so consistent. How can I learn Linux fast and consistently if there is no solid version of Linux out there?

PS. I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install `apt-doc`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-doc
```

Having a separate `-doc` package is not unusual.

Are you looking for something in particular?

Comment: as a new learner, im just trying to learn everything as fast as possible and i was very frustrated that teh man page was pointing me to something that didnt exist! but now i know that everything is seperated in order to bring the weight down? and only be downloaded when it is needed?

Comment: Indeed. Apt is something you'll have everywhere, from the smallest embedded device to your rack servers, ... Distributing docs separately is not systematic, but is good practice when you have lots of them

Comment: I'm trying to learn automation, so i can apply it to marketing, as a result i thought learning linux would be a good start. what do you think i am a complete newbie and know i have lots to learn.

Comment: If you're looking for automation, feel free to investigate on ansible or puppet, both of which I use daily and saved me countless hours, ...

Comment: oh wow... thanks for the resources.....do you have any resources on how to actually go about learning marketing and applying automation to it, so i can make money on the internet?